# WPF MVVM Console Output to a TextBox within a View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am writing an application that updates files and then will eventually import the updated files to a database. I want to display a message about which file is being updated and when the process has finished. I want the message to come from the console because eventually the importer library I am using displays helpful messages through the console and I will want to display those too. I was able to do this before in a WPF app, but all of my code was in the code behind of the view, and I want to keep the MVVM pattern and separate the code into a ViewModel. My problem is I do not know how to get a reference to my TextBox that is in my View. Once I am able to get a hold of the TextBox in my ViewModel I will be able to send the Console Writes to the TextBox.

Here is my View

```
<Window x:Class="DICOM_Importer.Views.StudyImporterView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DICOM_Importer.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="Gold"
        Title="Importer" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource gridBackground}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="280" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource studyTitle}}" Content="Study:" />
            <Label Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource studyTitle}}" Name="StudyImportViewStudyText" Content="{Binding ImporterTitle}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Label Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource studyTitle}}" Content="Import Directory" />
            <Label Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource studyTitle}}" Content="{Binding ImporterPath}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding ImportCommand}" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource buttonStyleImport}}" Content="Submit" />

        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ImportConsole" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the ViewModel

```
using DICOM_Importer.Commands;
using DICOM_Importer.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DICOM_Importer.ViewModels
{
    public class StudyImporterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private string importerTitle;
        private string importerPath;
        public DirectoryInfo[] directories;
        GetIndividualSubjectDirectories subjectDirectories = new GetIndividualSubjectDirectories();
        ConsoleOutputStream outputter;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the study information from the HomeView
        /// </summary>
        public String ImporterTitle
        {
            get { return importerTitle; }
            set
            {
                importerTitle = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImporterTitle");
            }
        }

        public String ImporterPath
        {
            get { return importerPath; }
            set
            {
                importerPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImporterPath");
            }
        }


        public StudyImporterViewModel()
        {
            ImportCommand = new ActivateImport(this);
            outputter = new ConsoleOutputStream(ImportConsole); //Here is where the error is
            Console.SetOut(outputter);
        }

        public ICommand ImportCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public void Import()
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("This will import every series in the Import Directory. Are you sure you want to Import?", "Import Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);


            switch (result)
            {
                case MessageBoxResult.OK:
                    if(importerTitle == "SPIROMICS2")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Importing SPIROMICS2 Scans to Mifar");
                        directories = subjectDirectories.GetSubjectDirectories(importerPath);
                        subjectDirectories.GetSeriesDirectories(directories);
                        Console.WriteLine("Import Complete");

                    }
                    else if(importerTitle == "BLF")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("BLF");
                    }
                    else if(importerTitle == "PRECISE")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("PRECISE");
                    }

                    break;
                case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                    MessageBox.Show("CANCEL", "Nope!");
                    break;
            }
        }

        #region Error Model
        public string Error
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Error Definition
        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get 
            {
                if (columnName == "ImporterTitle")
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ImporterPath))
                    {
                        Error = "There is no selected study to import";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Error = null;
                    }
                }
                return Error;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region PropertyChangedEventHandler
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion


    }
}
```

Here is my ConsoleOutputStream Command

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DICOM_Importer.Commands
{
    class ConsoleOutputStream : TextWriter
    {
        TextBox textBox = null;


        public ConsoleOutputStream(TextBox ouput)
        {
            textBox = ouput;
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                textBox.AppendText(value.ToString());
            }));
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the command for the button that will kick off all the file changes and imports

```
using DICOM_Importer.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DICOM_Importer.Commands
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the import processes on a button click if there is a study available 
    /// </summary>
    class ActivateImport : ICommand
    {

        private StudyImporterViewModel _studyImporterViewModel;

        public ActivateImport(StudyImporterViewModel viewModel)
        {
            _studyImporterViewModel = viewModel;
        }



        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            //this is forcing the CommandManager to check the ICommand again. If we didn't have this then the buitton wouldl only be 
            //disabled if the window was loaded with a blank name, not if it was loaded with a name and then was deleted by the user
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_studyImporterViewModel.Error);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _studyImporterViewModel.Import();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can't, in MVVM, get a reference to a view component from the viewmodel. That's breaking the pattern.

Comment: @sephiroth there is no way to bind the console write data from the ViewModel to the textbox in the View?

Comment: @millenniumThalken i think about a console app's output as a list of strings that we're fed one at a time. going this route, our view model would then have a `List<string>` property, maybe called `ConsoleOutputs`. so then our view would not have a `TextBox`, but maybe a `ListBox`, whose `ItemSource` is a `Binding` to our `ConsoleOutputs`. then, instead of using `ConsoleOutputStream` or even `Console`, we can just add new strings to `ConsoleOutputs`. when we add a new string to `ConsoleOutputs`, then through the magic of databinding our `ListView` will automaticallly be updated to display it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect the Console output to a `StringWriter` and then write its content into the string you bound to the textbox every time a new console output is made.

**ViewModel**

```cs
private StringWriter _sw;
public string ConsoleOut { /* getter and setter */ }

// inside constructor
_sw = new StringWriter();
Console.SetOut(sw);
Console.SetError(sw);
```

**xaml**

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ConsoleOut, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The problem here is that every time you want to display the console output in the TextBlock you need to update the value of S with `S = _sw.ToString();`

---

**Solution**

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3710257/9815377) with the implementation of an enhanced `StringWriter` class that fires an event every time there is a write. With this, you only need to make a simple update:

**ViewModel**

```cs
private StringWriterExt _sw;
public string ConsoleOut { /* getter and setter */ }

// inside constructor
_sw = new StringWriterExt(true);
Console.SetOut(sw);
Console.SetError(sw);
_sw.Flushed += (s, a) => ConsoleOut = _sw.ToString();
```

Comment: I have been going over the input and link you provided but still feel like I a coding in circles. I am not sure how to go about making the ConsoleOut Model class that would contain the getter and setter.

Comment: `public string ConsoleOut { get; set; }` should work just fine with that event handler on `_sw.Flushed`